# CSS - Add border around content + down dividing columns

Tags: css

I would like to add a border around and down each dividing column of content, but cannot seem to achieve that without reducing the size of the container, which in turn reduces the size of the content inside and makes everything look squished.

Here is an image of what I have:
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPB6j.jpg)

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Capture_edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHTmV.jpg)

I added the images to better communicate my goal, It is pretty self explanatory what I'm trying to do, is there a way I can achieve this efficiently?

I cannot understand how to get a border to go down the in between of the columns and connect with the border on the outside.

Here is a code snippet to further assist anyone who can help, all help is appreciated:

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
}
#site-wrap{
    padding:25px 10px;
}
li{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
section.li{
    max-width: 145px;
}
.stretch{
    height: 180px;
}
p{
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#sc1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-wrap">
 <div id="sc1">
    <section class="li">
        <h1 class="red">Do's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="li">
        <h1 class="red">Dont's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Never overload powerboards, piggyback or use multiple double adaptors.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Do not expose extension cord joins to the weather or join more than one extension cord together.</p>
    </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.flex-container` has margin but no padding.
- `.flex-child` has padding but no margin.
- Only every 2nd `.flex-child` has border left.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <section class="flex-child">
    <h1>Do's</h1>
    <p>Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
    <p>Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-child">
    <h1>Dont's</h1>
    <p>Never overload powerboards, piggyback or use multiple double adaptors.</p>
    <p>Do not expose extension cord joins to the weather or join more than one extension cord together.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** `flex-grow: 1` will allow the children of the flex item to expand and fill the parents width, it is better than max-width in your case and add the border on your `.li` class.

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
}
#site-wrap{
    padding:25px 10px;
}
li{
    margin: 10px 0;
}

section.li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em;  
}

section.li:nth-of-type(1) {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section.li:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}



.stretch{
    height: 180px;
}
p{
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#sc1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-wrap">
 <div id="sc1">
    <section class="li">
        <h1 class="red">Do's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="li">
        <h1 class="red">Dont's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Never overload powerboards, piggyback or use multiple double adaptors.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Do not expose extension cord joins to the weather or join more than one extension cord together.</p>
    </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so first you will need to look at [border-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) document, the trick here is to set

- border bottom, top, left, right on the left side `border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;`
- border top, right, bottom on the right side `border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;`
- then set border style and color (`border-color: #000; border-style: solid;`) along with it.

But first, you will need to remove `justify-content: space-evenly;` in `#sc1` cause your 2 `li` separate cause we need it to stick together, read more about [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

I suggest using `justify-content: center` but it's total up to you.

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
}
#site-wrap{
    padding:25px 10px;
}
li{
    margin: 10px 0;
}

section.li{
    max-width: 145px;
    /* --- new --- */
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;
    /* --- new --- */
}
/* --- new --- */
section.left{
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
section.right{
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
}
/* --- new --- */
.stretch{
    height: 180px;
}
p{
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#sc1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div id="site-wrap">
 <div id="sc1">
    <section class="li left">
        <h1 class="red">Do's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-check"></i> Always fully unroll extension cords to keep them from overheating.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="li right">
        <h1 class="red">Dont's</h1>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Never overload powerboards, piggyback or use multiple double adaptors.</p>
        <p class="stretch"><i class="fal fa-times"></i> Do not expose extension cord joins to the weather or join more than one extension cord together.</p>
    </section>
 </div>
</div>
```